# File operations doesn't work sometimes

Tags: java, android, file, directory

Something very strange is happenning in my app. I am creating 2 folders in the SD card if they not exist, and downloading some images from a URL if they not exist in the SD card. 
Sometimes, when I run the application, the program checks if the folders exists and also the images, as they are exists, it continues and there's nothing wrong.
But often when I run the application, it alerts me that the folders not exists and that it didn't even managed to create those folders, and afterwards I'm getting a "File not found exception" when it tries to download the images who already exists in my SD card.

P.S: I tried it with 2 devices and the same happens, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you checked at that time your device's sdcard was mounted on system or not?

Comment: @user370305 How can I check that?

Comment: Everytime before accessing files from your sdcard you have to check for state of external storage. Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: @user370305 I see, and what do I do if the sdcard is not available? I have to wait?

Comment: If file size are small then store these files temporary at `Internal Storage`.

Comment: @user370305 Alright, it really is the problem! the sd card is not available. so you say that I should store these files in Internal storage? it is 1mb size.

Comment: Only **1 mb** ? Then there is no problem to storing these files in Internal storage. Look at d link which I provided in my above comment for how to access Internal Storage in android.

Comment: @user370305 Wait, is it better to store these files in internal storage by default? or only if the external is not available?

Comment: @user370305 And please, set your answer as an answer, so I can accept it, you helped me alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually before accessing files from external storage you have to check whether `External storage` **is present (Available) or not on device** (It possible if device's sdcard is mounted on System). For this You have to check the sate of External Storage as Mounted or Not.

Look at this Link for more info..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Now solution:

If you find external storage is not available then you can store your files at `Internal Storage` on temporary basis (Then you can move these files to External Storage when it present).

So My link also help you in how to access Internal Storage in Android.

Comment: If your files are not burden for device internal memory (small in size) then Let it would be in Internal Storage. Not any issues.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been busy on other stuff, thanks for the detailed answer. A question: is it possible to create folders in the internal storage also ?

Comment: Yes, You can create a folder in Internal Storage of Application. Also if this answer is helpful to you, you can accept as a correct answer and vote up it. It will helpful to you and other user also.

Comment: I was just going to do that now :) thanks alot for your helping! I'm going to try it now on my application, and I'll be happy if you could still help me if I have any problems during the developing.

Comment: How can I create 2 nested folders? I manage to create only one.

Comment: Android Internal Storage is same File directory as External Storage. You can create any number of directories and files also nested unless its size matter (Memory Issues).